# changing the class of clicked button on ajax function success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a several html buttons (not within a form).

When clicked they call a JavaScript function that after conformation, runs an ajax call.
This part all works OK, but i would then like to change the class of whichever button was clicked on success of the ajax call.

i have tried various methods seen on stackOverflow, but none of them seem to work...
can i please ask what am i doing wrong?

here is the simplified HTML (buttons)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="primaryImage(4107,19372,'/abbie1.jpg'); return false;">
set as profile image
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="primaryImage(4107,19373,'/abbie2.jpg'); return false;">
set as profile image
</button>

<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="primaryImage(4107,19374,'/abbie3.jpg'); return false;" disabled="disabled">
profile image
</button>
```

Please note: the last button is already the active/success button, and i would also like to remove the class on success too (as only one should be active), but that is maybe my next stage....

here is the javaScript, (i have left in some of the methods i have tried, but commented them out)

```
function primaryImage(eid,pid)
    {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to use this as your profile image?"))
        {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                url: "ajax_photo.php",
                data: "action=primary&eid="+eid+"&pid="+pid,
                //context: this,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.result=='success')
                    {
                        alert('The image is now set as the profile image');
                        //$('button').click(function(){
                        //   $(this).addClass('btn-success');
                        //});

                        //$('button').on(data.result=='success', function(e) {
                        //  $(this).toggleClass("btn btn-success"); //you can list several class names 
                        //  e.preventDefault();
                        //});

                        //$(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('An error occurred when trying to set the image: ' + data.result);
                    }
               }
            });
        }
    }
```

I would be very grateful for any advice of what i am doing wrong
(as you can see, i am not too good with JS (yet))

Thanks!
Ford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in your commented out code, you are binding the click event *after* click event has *already been fired*.

I would suggest you to pass a ***reference*** of the button that was clicked in the `primaryImage()` function itself as such:

```
 <!-- In your HTML -->
 <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="primaryImage(this, 4107,19374,'/abbie3.jpg'); return false;" disabled="disabled">
profile image
</button>
```

---

```
 function primaryImage(button, eid,pid){
  /** ... */
```

Then using that referenced button, you can add or remove CSS classes to the element, as well as the *siblings* of the element (using jQuery's `siblings()` method).

```
            //your ajax call
            success: function(data){
                if(data.result=='success') //make sure this really is success
                {
                    alert('The image is now set as the profile image');
                    $(button).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');
                    $(button).siblings('button').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary');
                }
          }
```

Comment: thanks even removes the class from other buttons and the disabled with a little tweaking as my sample HTML was not what is being used, to : $('.profileImage > .center > button').removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-primary').prop("disabled", false);

Answer (score 1):

As you don't use the jQuery .click() event, I think you need to pass the button in your function args.

So your button will look like

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="primaryImage(this, 4107,19373,'/abbie2.jpg'); return false;">
    set as profile image
</button>
```

Then your function will be like

```
function primaryImage(el, eid,pid)
{

    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to use this as your profile image?"))
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://anzvirtuel.org",
            data: "action=primary&eid="+eid+"&pid="+pid,
            //context: this,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.result=='success')
                {
                    $(el).addClass('btn-success');

                    alert('The image is now set as the profile image');

                    // keep doing whatever you want...
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('An error occurred when trying to set the image: ' + data.result);
                }
           }
        });
    }
}
```

As I have not fully understood your commented JS I'll let you put the code you want, just remember that your button will be accessible in jQuery with `$(el)`.

Hope it may helps you

Comment: thanks, works well. sorry about my other commented JS i didnt understand the element was not available with in the function, but it now works perfectly with help of the other answers too and stackOverflow even removed the other active button and the disabled property! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the clicked element to the primaryImage() function, and use it on success to do whatever you like.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="primaryImage(this, 4107,19372,'/abbie1.jpg'); return false;">set as profile image</button>
```

And in your JS

```
function primaryImage(element, eid,pid)
{
    [...]
         success: function(data){
             if(data.result=='success')
             {
                 $(element).addClass('btn-success');
             }
             else
             {
                 alert('An error occurred when trying to set the image: ' + data.result);
             }
         }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data-*` attributes instead of `onclick` ([MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)) and then access those throught jQuery, so your code is more clean and HTML / JS are separated.

Try this code, I've created three `data` attributes (`data-eid`, `data-pid` and `data-image`) for your params and also replaced your JS to make the whole stuff work with those `data` attributes. Those attributes can be accessed with following jQuery code - `var eid = $(this).attr('data-eid');` as an example

This line of code removes the `btn-primary` class from the clicked button, adds a `btn-success` class to it and disables it, so it can't be toggled again.

`pushedBtn.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success").prop("disabled", true);`

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-eid="4107" data-pid="19372" data-image="/abbie1.jpg">
    profile image
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-eid="4107" data-pid="19373" data-image="/abbie2.jpg">
    profile image
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-eid="4107" data-pid="19374" data-image="/abbie3.jpg">
    profile image
</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".btn").click(function (e) {
if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to use this as your profile image?")) {
    var eid = $(this).attr('data-eid'); //like 4107
    var pid = $(this).attr('data-pid'); //like 19372
    var image = $(this).attr('data-image'); //like /abbie1.jpg
    var pushedBtn = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ajax_photo.php",
        data: "action=primary&eid=" + eid + "&pid=" + pid,
        //context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.result == 'success') {
                alert('The image is now set as the profile image');
                    pushedBtn.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success").prop("disabled", true);


            } else {
                alert('An error occurred when trying to set the image: ' + data.result);
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: No problem, here is an example (with a jsonplaceholder API), so you can see the data-attributes are being submitted and the data you get can be checked. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oyLm2fx5/1/)